# Python - "Keyword cannot be an expression"

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I know this error message has been discussed on here before but I still cannot figure out how to make this work. I'm trying to do a np.where statement with more than one condition. Below is my code. I am getting the error message "Keyword can't be an expression" and it is highlighting the space after "aggregate['Counter'] > 1.

```
aggregate['1'] = np.where(np.logical_and(aggregate['Counter'] > 1, aggregate['2'].shift(1) = aggregate['3']), 0, aggregate['2'])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`:

```
...aggregate['2'].shift(1) == aggregate['3']),...
                           ^^ here
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need a double equals sign:

```
aggregate['1'] = np.where(np.logical_and(aggregate['Counter'] > 1, aggregate['2'].shift(1) == aggregate['3']), 0, aggregate['2']
```